# IMU Calibration on Ground Robot - how do people do it?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on a ground based robot, and now we are working to install an IMU.

At the moment we are using this IMU: https://www.adafruit.com/product/24721. We are trying to figure out calibration with it however - how do people typically install and allow for calibration of an IMU on a ground based robot? Do they typically install it on a lead such that it can be moved in patterns to calibrate it fully? Or are there calibration free IMUs that can be installed and simply work when turned on seamlessly?

If there are calibration free IMUs, what ones do people recommend?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271818/imu-calibration-on-ground-robot---how-do-people-do-it?/) by [candersen10](https://answers.ros.org/users/30570/candersen10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2017-09-29**:
Your link does not appear to work.  404 not found error.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2017-09-29**:
What do you mean by ground based?  Do you mean it cannot be moved?  Can it be tilted at all?  Rotated?

**Comment by [candersen10](https://answers.ros.org/users/30570/candersen10/) on 2017-09-29**:
This is the link to the IMU: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2472

By ground based I mean a 150-500+ pound robot that cannot be tilted/rotated the way you might rotate/move around a lightweight drone to calibrate the IMU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you install the IMU on a lead and then pull it away from the mounting location to perform the calibration, then you're defeating much of the purpose of the calibration.  The calibration should be done with the IMU mounted in its operational location and with the robot powered on.  Maybe even with the robot moving.  That way, any magnetic fields and metallic parts that can affect the IMU can attempt to be calibrated out.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [candersen10](https://answers.ros.org/users/30570/candersen10/) on 2017-09-29**:
Kurt, got it.  How then do you calibrate an IMU on a heavy robot that you can't move around in different patterns (i.e. figure eight pattern across the Z axis)?  Is there any standardized approach to doing this?

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2017-10-02**:
This is really out of my domain.  But I suspect that if you move/drive the robot around in it's normal axis of motion during your IMU calibration, that the IMU will work well in that axis of operation.  And I suspect that it won't give you much data in the unused axes.  Not sure though.